# How do you create a cpp file to make different nodes work together? e.g. a robot to follow people around

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using the kinect_tracker  and p2os_driver base,but i cant seem to make it work with the current cpp that my fren left me with

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85001/how-do-you-create-a-cpp-file-to-make-different-nodes-work-together?-e.g.-a-robot-to-follow-people-around/) by [chillyster](https://answers.ros.org/users/7236/chillyster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume by "make different nodes work together" you mean "how to make nodes to communicate with each other".

Please see the answer for this question in [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), particularly [Understanding ROS Nodes](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes), [Understanding ROS Topics](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics) and [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0